# there is an error in the second client.event it shows ( Shard ID None WebSocket closed with 4004discord.gateway.WebSocketClosure:)

Tags: python, discord, bots

```
import discord

token = "*******"

intents = discord.Intents.default()

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event

async def on_ready():

    print(f"Bot logged in as {client.user}")

@client.event(this part)

async def on_message(msg):

    if msg.author != client.user:

        if msg.content.lower().startswith("?hi"):

            await msg.channel.send(f"Hi, {msg.author.display_name}")

client.run(token)(this part)
```

Normally when u say hi to the bot it should answer you